# Manipulate WebPage Navigation in Android (Running Application)

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, phonegap-plugins, adb

I'm doing some security testing on an android application. I'd like to know if there's a simple way to manipulate the state of the application via some tool or through the command line (adb?). The application is based on web views (Cordova in particular) and has several states that can be navigated to using forward and back buttons. The only way to change these states is by using those buttons. What if for example I'd like to move states sequentially (assuming I know the URLs - which I do in this case). If I'm using a browser I could simply change what's in the address bar but in an android app this is more difficult.

For example:

page 1 = mobileApp.jsp?page=1

page 2 = mobileApp.jsp?page=2

page 3 = mobileApp.jsp?page=3

You get the idea. If I'm currently on page 3, I can only move forward to page 4 or back to page 2. What if I want to move to page 1 directly from 3?

Could this be done with intents? Without access to the source code?

Any tips or suggestions would be welcomed! I have a .APK from the developers compiled in debug mode and that's it.